# System.Reflection получить экземпляр класса

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Какой метод в Reflection может дать мне пустой экземпляр класса?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Activator.CreateInstance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var instance = (ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ObjectType));
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Answer (score 1):

Есть и немного другой способ создания экземпляра, пример Generic - метода для создания экземпляра объекта заданного типа:

```
public static T GetNewObject<T>()
{
    var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] {});
    if (constructor != null)
    {
        return (T) constructor.Invoke(new object[] {});
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

В отличие от `Activator.CreateInstance` - данный метод не выбросит исключение, в случае, если для объекта не определено беспараметрических конструкторов, будет возвращено значение `null`.

Ссылка на источник: [Get a new object instance from a Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753/5275890) - там есть и другие ответы, которые будут полезны, но я решил выделить этот.

> Метод [Type.GetConstructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx) - выполняет поиск открытого
>   конструктора экземпляра, параметры которого соответствуют типам,
>   содержащимся в указанном массиве.
>
> Метод [MethodBase.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) - вызывает метод или конструктор,
>   представленный текущим экземпляром, используя указанные параметры.
>
> Выражение [default(T)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) - выражения значения по умолчанию, которое
>   создает значение по умолчанию с типом `T`.

Конечно же, использовать подход с помощью [Activator.CreateInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755/5275890) намного проще и удобнее, как уже был дан ответ от [@free_ze](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6761/free-ze)

Comment: [Как выясняется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860921/218063) Activator работает быстрее

Comment: @АндрейNOP рефлексия всегда была немного медленной.