# Существует ли возможность создавать объект определенного типа, без использования класса Activator?

Tags: c#

Для приведения типов наследуемого объекта написана функция. Есть-ли какая-либо возможность создать объект нужного типа без использования класса Activator?

```
public T ToObject<T>()
{
     var o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
     ...
     return (T)o 
}
```

Comment: Хорошо. Можно с помощью рефлексии получить конструктор и вызвать его, но по факту это будет то же самое, что и Activator, но будет чуть больше кода

Comment: Т.е. данный код по производительности не составит слишком большой проблемы? Я делаю класс, который создает из sql таблиц классы, из процедур функции. Так вот приведение SQL результата, к коллекции созданных автоматически классов требует вот такой вот функции. Объектов может быть очень не маленькое количество.

Comment: С другой стороны, если вам нужно создавать много объектов одного типа, возможно будет эффективнее получить конструктор один раз и использовать его.

Comment: для массива объектов я создаю лист T -  System.Collections.Generic.List<T> iL = new System.Collections.Generic.List<T>();
а засовываю с помощью вот этого самого объекта(После наполнения нужным из sql результата)  -  iL.Add((T)o);

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что если вы создаете много объектов, то может быть эффективнее получить конструктор один раз `typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);` и закешировать его, а потом просто вызывать его для создания объектов, чем запрашивать конструктор каждый раз (Activator работает тоже через рефлексию)

Comment: Еще более эффективным может быть создание делегата. В общем надо тестировать

Comment: Совсем недавно был похожий вопрос: [System.Reflection получить экземпляр класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857652/189339)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я написал простой тест для `BenchmarkDotNet`:

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Creator
{
    public class A { }

    [Benchmark]
    public A ExplicitCtor()
    {
        return new A();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public A WithActivator()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<A>();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public A WithReflection()
    {
        return (A)typeof(A).GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[0]);
    }

    ConstructorInfo ctor;
    [Benchmark]
    public A WithReflectionCached()
    {
        if (ctor == null) ctor = typeof(A).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        return (A)ctor.Invoke(new object[0]);
    }

    Func<A> lambda;
    [Benchmark]
    public A WithLambla()
    {
        if (lambda == null)
            lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<A>>(Expression.New(typeof(A)), Array.Empty<ParameterExpression>()).Compile();
        return lambda();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public A WithCustomActivator()
    {
        return CustomActivator.CreateInstance<A>();
    }
}
```

<sub>(`CustomActivator` by Sergey Teplyakov можно взять [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608238/218063))</sub>

Результаты получились следующие:

```
|               Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |     Median |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
|--------------------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|-----------:|-------:|----------:|
|         ExplicitCtor |   2.591 ns | 0.0523 ns | 0.0489 ns |   2.582 ns | 0.0076 |      12 B |
|        WithActivator | 113.661 ns | 0.4652 ns | 0.3885 ns | 113.583 ns | 0.0074 |      12 B |
|       WithReflection | 369.719 ns | 6.9477 ns | 5.4243 ns | 367.856 ns | 0.0229 |      36 B |
| WithReflectionCached | 281.290 ns | 0.9358 ns | 0.7814 ns | 281.415 ns | 0.0148 |      24 B |
|           WithLambla |  17.391 ns | 0.0700 ns | 0.0621 ns |  17.373 ns | 0.0076 |      12 B |
|  WithCustomActivator |  27.644 ns | 0.6665 ns | 1.3155 ns |  27.039 ns | 0.0076 |      12 B |
```

Т.е. что мы видим: рефлексия очень медленная и даже кеширование конструктора не сильно помогает, создание объекта с помощью `Activator` быстрее явной рефлексии в 2,5-3 раза, но всё еще сильно медленнее явного вызова конструктора (в 40 раз!), наиболее эффективный метод, как и ожидалось — создание и кеширование делегата, создающего объекты, он всего в ~6 раз медленнее явного вызова конструктора (тут, подозреваю, медленное именно создание делегата, а сам его вызов не должен уступать явному вызову конструктора, т.е. чем больше объектов мы будем создавать, тем ближе будет средняя скорость к идеальной).

Таким образом, имеет смысл переписать ваш метод во что-то вроде такого:

```
Dictionary<Type, Delegate> cache = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();
public T Create<T>()
{
    if (!cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var d))
        d = cache[typeof(T)]
            = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(
                Expression.New(typeof(T)),
                Array.Empty<ParameterExpression>())
            .Compile();
    return ((Func<T>)d)();
}
```

Comment: и вот из этого ответа: [@SergeyTeplyakov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608238/186999) добавь вариант c `public static class CustomActivator`

Comment: Хм, да это тоже самое что и у меня же

Comment: не совсем, там код немного попроще выглядит: обычный `new T()`, а у тебя работа напрямую с Expression, ты полностью руками собираешь вызов

Comment: Да не совсем, прогнал тесты, за счет `where T : new()` код Теплякова оказался даже медленнее! Собирать лямбду руками выходит эффективнее

Comment: Можешь результаты в ответ добавить? :-)

Comment: Хотя, похоже, именно поиск метода здесь медленнее, а не `where T : new()`, переписал свой метод как у Теплякова в виде дженерик-класса и получил те же самые 27 нс. Вариант со словарем быстрее

Comment: В любом случае 27ms намного лучше 113ms, а запись осталась такой же удобной

Comment: Кстати можно еще добавить простой вызов `new T()` хоть он внутри и вызывает тот же самый Activator

Comment: Большое спасибо за внимание к вопросу, сейчас опробую на практике.

Comment: по созданию объектов узкое место пропало, отлично. Спасибо :)