# Производительность рефлексии

Tags: c#

Подскажите, если я найду все необходимые мне свойства и сохраню `PropertyInfo` в какой-нибудь словарь, то при последующей работе через эту переменную будет ли выше производительность или все равно она будет достаточно медленной чем обычное присвоение?

Просто, интереса ради.

Comment: Цитата от долгожителя с прошлой работы : "Если ты задумываешься сколько стоит приведение типа, то ты явно что то не то делаешь и проблема в оптимизации в чем то другом".

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, да не, я не собираюсь ее использовать в безумных количествах. Просто интересны вопросы производительности и способы ее повышения.

Comment: Возможно связанный вопрос: [Существует ли возможность создавать объект определенного типа, без использования класса Activator?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860921/186999) и еще один: [Способы создания объектов в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715920/186999)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... сохраню PropertyInfo в какой-нибудь словарь, то при последующей работе через эту переменную будет ли выше производительность ...

Да, производительность будет выше чем если получать `PropertyInfo` каждый раз для каждого свойства заново. Вы сэкономите на проверках доступа к типу, загрузке его метаданных.

> или все равно она будет достаточно медленной чем обычное присвоение?

Всегда работа со свойствами будет медленнее через рефлексию, хотя бы потому, что теряется возможность оптимизации на уровне Just-in-Time компиляции.

Кроме того, [`PropertyInfo.SetValue`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/propertyinfo.cs,647) будет медленнее обычного присвоения, т.к. выполняет больше работы: проверяет наличие сеттера, права доступа к нему, обрабатывает присваимые значения.

Можно попробовать улучшить производительность засчет уменьшения лишней работы:

- получить у свойства сразу ссылку на метод присвоения, через [`PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_GetSetMethod);
- использовать метод [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Delegate_CreateDelegate_System_Type_System_Object_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_), который умеет делать из метода, полученного при помощи рефлексии, строго типизированный делегат.

Получится что-то вроде:

```
//получаем делегат
var setterDelegate =
            (Action<CustomClass, int>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                //тип сеттера <класс, тип присваиваемого значения>
                typeof (Action<CustomClass, int>),
                null,
                //свойство
                typeof (CustomClass).GetProperty("Property").GetSetMethod());
//делегат кэшируем и вызываем так.
setterDelegate(obj, value);
```

Что, *предположительно*, должно быть быстрее нежели `PropertyInfo` и, опять-таки *предположительно* медленнее чем прямое присваивание. На практике нужно будет замерять какой вариант окажется быстрее и почему.

Comment: А для полей есть какие-то лайф-хаки?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Хмм, такого я не знаю. В [`FieldInfo`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/fieldinfo.cs,329d417f4b15c86c) происходит много всего и я не знаю как это обойти.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Нашел такой подход, но не проверял его: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528620/c-sharp-fieldinfo-reflection-alternatives