# C#. Возможно ли инстанциировать с помощью активатора объект интерфейса без каста?

Tags: c#, динамическая-типизация

C#. Возможно ли инстанциировать с помощью активатора объект интерфейса без каста (я знаю тип объекта, который нужно инстанциировать, и объект заведомо имплементирует интерфейс).

В простом случае, создать (используя конструктор по умолчанию) динамически объект нужного типа можно так:

```
object newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(ObjectType)
```

Получить объект интерфейса можно так:

```
IObjectInterface newObject = (IObjectInterface )Activator.CreateInstance(ObjectType)
```

ну либо просто:

```
object newObject = (IObjectInterface )Activator.CreateInstance(ObjectType)
```

(у полученного объекта будут доступны все методы интерфейса).

Чего я хочу добиться, так это примерно динамического аналога следующей строчки кода без типизации:

```
IObjectInterface newObject = new ObjectType();
```

Например, как мне представляется, что-то вроде:

```
var newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type: ObjectType, interface: IObjectInterface, //ну и здесь, если надо параметры для передачи в качестве аргументов конструктора);
```

Comment: Мгм. Похоже, что Activator спроектирован так, что нужно выбрать что-то одно: либо шашечки, либо ехать. В одном случае вы знаете тип и передаёте на конструктор тип (CreateInstance(Type) и перегрузки) и получаете тип - но хотя var выводится в конкретный Type нужно явно указывать в коде какой интерфейс реализуется, к чему кастить. В других перегрузках вы на var получаете либо название интерфейса без конкретики, либо вообще object. Так что штатно - нет. А вот нештатно... вас устраивает залезть в потроха `t.GetType().GetInterfaces()` в рантайме?

Comment: Ну то есть использовать рефлексию имеете ввиду. Я этот вопрос задал, потому что во всех видео, что смотрел, говорят избегать каста везде, где это возможно. И поскольку такая ситуация у меня возникла в коде, решил исследовать сей прецедент на предмет существования окольных путей. Если использовать рефлексию, то соответственно возникает вопрос, что хуже. Каст или рефлексия) А вообще, я просто сейчас занят другими делами, и скорее всего найду ответ на свой вопрос в понедельник, когда засяду опять за код. Просто хотел посмотреть что такого интересного народ предложит.

Comment: Точнее куда-то сюда: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Select(x => x.GetInterfaces())`. Ну просто посудите сами. У вас в голове есть знание, что некий тип что-то реализует. Вы а) знаете название типа б) уверены что получится скастить без эксепшена. Можно захардкодить "скасть к такому-то типу" тип будет известен уже в compile time, можно окольно придти к имени типа в рантайме - но гарантии условия "б" уже нет, надо писать какие-то доп. проверки. А вопрос "что хуже" для  вас - это вопрос производительности? Если так, то каст очевидно дешевле.

Comment: Ну, если каст дешевле, то у меня как раз тот случай, когда он оправдан. Спасибо вам за ответы!

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860921/218063) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715920/218063)